# Firebase Login signIn Linkedin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, linkedin-api, firebase-authentication

I want to implement login with Linkedin in my iOS app using Firebase. I create the session, but when I call the FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn it looks like that in Firebase library the completion block is not called and it never "returns", so (in the code below) it never prints anything.

```
LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
        guard let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session else { return }
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: session.accessToken.accessTokenValue) { (user, error) in
            //Never enter here, never prints anything
            print(error)
            print(user)
        }
    }) { (error) -> Void in }
```

Has anyone any idea to fix this problem?

**SOLVED:**

The problem with login (linkedin, but any kind of login) is the callback. Just set the right callback url and it worked.

Comment: Firebase Authentication doesn't support LinkedIn as a provider by default.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen indeed I'm doing with withCustomToken, I just get the token and then signIn with custom Token

Comment: @NazmulHasan it's not duplicate as in that post you suggest, they say it's possible to do any login implementing a custom login which is what I'm doing here. The problem is that it looks that something happens in "FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken" and "they" don't call completion

Comment: @Andrea.Ferrando when I use the same token to signInWithCustom I get an error saying the token is not the right format.